# Is there a way to rollback a committed offset in Kafka?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

How can I rollback / undo an offset commit in a case like this (see the comment in catch block)?

```
public void HandleMessage(ConsumeResult<object, int> messageResult, IConsumer consumer) {
     try {
         consumer.commit(messageResult);
         
         dbProvider.startTransaction();
         //Do db operations
         dbProvider.commit();

     } 
     catch (Exception ex) {
         dbProvider.rollBack();

         //How do I undo kafka commit here?
     }
}
```

Basically, I first want to commit the kafka offset, and commit to database. If database transaction fails, I want to rollback the offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can seek the consumer group backwards and commit a previous offset, yes.

However, I don't see being much different than committing after the database transaction completes